# How to shrink a Windows XP VMWare Fusion virtual machine?

Tags: virtualization, vmware

Is it possible to shrink a VM Ware Fusion Virtual Machine, and if so how? Specifically a Windows XP guest/client?

I've found old references to procedures purported to make this possible, but they reference a VM Ware DiskTool that appears to no longer be available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VMWare Fusion 3. There are 2 parts

Prerequisites are the VM cannot have any snapshots and the virtual disk does not have a preallocated size. [Making virtual disk sparse](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=1021565)

[**Clean up Windows**](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=1001934)

I would then in Windows run the MS Disk Cleanup tool to remove files and then Disk Defragmentor to put all the space in one place.

VMWare tools includes a [shrink disk command](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vmware-tools-installation-configuration.pdf)

Then power off the VM

**Clean up the virtual disk**

Search for `Clean Up a Hard Disk` in Fusion's help

> 1
>   From the VMware Fusion menu bar, select Window > Virtual Machine Library.
>   2
>   Click the thumbnail of the virtual machine and click Settings at the bottom of the library window.
>   3
>   Under Removable Devices in the Settings window, select Hard Disks.
>   4
>    In the Hard Disks panel, select the hard disk in the source list.
>   5  Click Clean Up Disk in the Disk Cleanup section.
>
> VMware Fusion displays a progress dialog as it cleans up the virtual
>   disk.

Comment: Thanks, It worked!  I finally found a couple KB articles on VMWare site (very hard to find via search) that I added to your answer.